# (Why) Is it not possible to encapsulate the pagination creating in a Factory in ZF2?

Tags: pagination, zend-framework2, dependencies, paginator, zend-paginator

Currently I'm creating my `Paginator` objects in `Mapper`s like this:

```
$sql = new Sql($this->dbAdapter);
$select = $sql->select('my_table');
$select->from(...)->columns(...)->join(...)->where(...)...;
$adapter = new MyPaginatorAdapter($select, $this->dbAdapter);
$paginator = new Paginator($adapter);
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
```

That means, the class has multiple hard dependencies, that should be better injected. But how to do this, when the `PaginatorAdapter` needs a `Select` object on instantiating? It also has now setter for this.

(Why) Is it (by design?) not possible to create a `Paginator` in a Factory and add it as injected dependency?

Comment: Why would you not be able to create a `Paginator` in a factory?